# How to remove duplicate dictionaries based on 2 keys?

Tags: python

I want to remove duplicate dictionaries based on 2 keys. Is there a faster way to do this?

What I've tried so far.

```
def remove_duplicates(documents):
    unique_documents = [documents[0]]  # Initialize first dict
    for document in documents:
        for index, unique_document in enumerate(unique_documents):
            if unique_document['user'] == document['user']:
                if unique_document['text'] == document['text']:
                    # If the user and text are found, then it's a duplicate.
                    # Go to next document.
                    break
                if index == len(unique_documents)-1:
                    # If it reaches the last dict of the unique_documents,
                    # append to list because the dict is unique
                    unique_documents.append(document)

    return unique_documents
```

There are 7 keys per dict in the list of dicts and using the code above with a test data of **99942** **documents** took **1457.94099998s** or **24mins** to process. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach takes O(N**2) time in the worst case (all documents are unique you loop over all unique documents for each document tested).

Use a separate set to track user-text tuples you've already seen, that way you can reduce this to a O(N) algorithm, independent of the number of unique documents. Sets allow you to test for the presence of an object in O(1) time, removing the need for the nested loop:

```
def remove_duplicates(documents):
    unique_documents = []
    seen = set()
    for document in documents:
        if (document['user'], document['text']) in seen:
            continue
        unique_documents.append(document)
        seen.add((document['user'], document['text']))

    return unique_documents
```

Comment: From **1457.94099998s** to **1.03100013733s**! Thanks!